# integate $\int\sqrt{x^2+3x+3} dx$

Tags: integration, substitution

Is there any universal method how to solve integrals like this?
$$\int\sqrt{x^2+3x+3} dx$$
Or this?
$$\int\sqrt{-x^2+3x+3} dx$$
I tried use first Euler subs, but it was not good idea. 
$$\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c} = t\pm\sqrt{ax}$$

Comment: I'd say start by completing the square

Comment: [Euler's substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). Generally solves every integral of the form $\int R\left(x,\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}\right)\, dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any integral of the forms, you have mentioned, 
transform the integrand into the sum or difference of two perfect square expressions and the resulting expression will look like  $\sqrt{(x\pm a)^2+(b)^2}$ ,$\sqrt{(x\pm a)^2-(b)^2}$  or $\sqrt{(b)^2-(x\pm a)^2}$.

And then use the following formulae which can be deduced with the help of integration by parts:

1. $$\sqrt{(x\pm a)^2+(b)^2}dx=\frac{(x\pm a)\sqrt{(x\pm a)^2+(b)^2}}{2}+\frac{b^2}{2}\ln |(x\pm a)+\sqrt{(x\pm a)^2+(b)^2}|$$
2. $$\sqrt{(x\pm a)^2-(b)^2}dx=\frac{(x\pm a)\sqrt{(x\pm a)^2-(b)^2}}{2}-\frac{b^2}{2}\ln |(x\pm a)+\sqrt{(x\pm a)^2-(b)^2}|$$
3. $$\sqrt{(b)^2-(x\pm a)^2}dx=\frac{(x\pm a)\sqrt{(b)^2-(x\pm a)^2}}{2}+\frac{b^2}{2}\sin \frac{x\pm a}{b}$$

Hope you can apply this to your problem and solve it now.

Comment: Thanks, what is true? 
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} = \ln|..|$$ or $$= \ln(...)$$ because i find some table of basic integrals and there was = ln()

Comment: @DavidM Truly speaking, $\ln|...|$ is correct since $\ln$ of negative things are undefined. However for some specific calculations, we may consider the inside expression to be positive and hence omit the mod sign. That might be incorrect but we need it to suit our purpose.

Answer (score 2):

For the first: complete the square to rewrite this as
$$
\sqrt{(x+3/2)^2 + 3/4}
$$
Now, apply a substitution $\theta$ such that
$$
x+3/2= \sqrt{3/4}\tan \theta
$$
For the second: complete the square to rewrite the integrand as
$$
\sqrt{k - (x-3/2)^2}
$$
For some $k$ that I'm too lazy to calculate. Then, apply a substitution such that
$$
x-3/2= \sqrt k \sin \theta
$$

Answer (score 2):

By a linear transform of the argument, you can normalize the integrand to one of

$$\sqrt{1+x^2}\text{ or }\sqrt{1-x^2}.$$

Then by parts,

$$\int\sqrt{1\pm x^2}\,dx=x\sqrt{1\pm x^2}\mp\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1\pm x^2}}dx=x\sqrt{1\pm x^2}-\int\frac{(1\pm x^2)-1}{\sqrt{1\pm x^2}}dx.$$

Move the first part of the integral to the LHS and remains to integrate
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1\pm x^2}},$$ which is elementary.